# Bootstrap carousel adjust height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, carousel, responsive

I'm new in Bootstrap and I have a question about carousel. I need to set a height of 700px on big screens (pcs) and a height of 500px for cell phones. How can I do it? I put this:

```
 @media (min-width: 320px){
    .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    }
    .carousel {
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    }

    .carousel .item {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #777;
    }
    .carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    }

}
```

I wait for a response.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it right know, but if you want to have the 500px height in devices with a width smaller than 320px you're media query should be `@media (max-height:320px)` instead of `@media (min-width:320px)`.

EDIT:

I tested it and this way works:

```
@media (max-width:320px){
  .carousel{
     height:50px;
   }
}
```

This way from resolutions that have width from 0 to 320, the `.carousel` class will have 50px of height.

If this solve your problem please don't forget to vote up and select this answer :)

Comment: Thanks for response! I had tested this but I think that I'm wrong because I don't know how must I use the media querie. For example, I use `@media (max-height:320px){...code 1...} @media (min-height:760px){...code 2...} and out of a media querie I put code 1 with other height values (this is understandable?)
If you don't understand me, I try to be more clearer!

Comment: I don't know if I understand you but I think I made an error too. It's max-width:320px (the width of resolution) and when you've got that width or less you want the carousel to have height:500px . Try this way please. If this doesn't work try to use max-height:500px;

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I solve this using another solution (I adjust height to 100% and this works better!). Anyway, I prove your tip but didn't work...